# how to calculate time duration from two date/time values using jq

Tags: json, datetime, jq, duration

I have some json that looks like this....

```
[
  {
    "start": "20200629T202456Z",
    "end": "20200629T211459Z",
    "tags": [
      "WPP",
      "WPP review tasks, splashify popup",
      "clients",
      "work"
    ],
    "annotation": "update rules, fix drush errors, create base wpp-splash module."
  },
  {
    "start": "20200629T223000Z",
    "end": "20200629T224641Z",
    "tags": [
      "WPP",
      "WPP review tasks, splashify popup",
      "clients",
      "work"
    ]
  },
 ]
```

and I want to show a duration of hours:minutes instead of "start" and "end" times.

The time format might be a little unusual(?), it's coming from timewarrior.  I imagine this would be easier for `jq` to accomplish if the date/time were stored in a normal unix timestamp, but maybe this is still possible?  Could jq write the output like

```
[
  {
    "time": "0:50:03",
    "tags": [
      "WPP",
      "WPP review tasks, splashify popup",
      "clients",
      "work"
    ],
    "annotation": "update rules, fix drush errors, create base wpp-splash module."
  }
]
```

or something similar.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For clarity, let's define a helper function:

```
def duration($finish; $start):
  def twodigits: "00" + tostring | .[-2:];
  [$finish, $start]
  | map(strptime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ") | mktime) # seconds
  | .[0] - .[1]
  | (. % 60 | twodigits) as $s
  | (((. / 60) % 60) | twodigits)  as $m
  | (./3600 | floor) as $h
  | "\($h):\($m):\($s)" ;
```

The solution is now simply:

```
map( {time: duration(.end;.start)} + del(.start,.end) )
```

Comment: Is that python?  Or does jq allow helper function to be defined?  How would I use that in a pipeline of linux commands?  Would I need to put that in an executable file?  How do I pass my stream of json data to it?

Comment: That's jq, which supports (nested) defs, but they must appear before the `main` program.  If in doubt, I'd suggest you consider using jq's `-f` command-line option, but in a script (e.g. a bash script), you can inline the jq program quite nicely. I'd also suggest you take the time to browse through the jq documentation online.

Comment: Could you give an example of implementation?  I've never scripted with jq before and have only used it in simple pipelines like `timew export | jq` and not sure how the code you gave fits into that workflow.  I'm trying and floundering...

Comment: oh... so if I just do in a shell script `jq 'def duration...etc the rest of your code'` I'm able to pipe the stream of json data to that shell script, so now it's `timew export | jq-tw-duration.sh`.  Thanks <3